# How to perform operations in forEach and pass it to groupingBy in Java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to divide a list of mine based on a certain decision. I also have a map which stores these decisions.
Currently I am updating the decision in the stream itself. I feel this isn't good practice as I am using collect to do
operations other than figuring out the grouping criteria. Another option I have is to go through the stream again 
and use forEach to update the map, but then it would mean that I am using getFinalDecision twice. Is there a better approach? Is there a way 
I can perform the getFinalDecision in forEach and pass it to groupingBy?

```
val test = myList.stream().collect(groupingBy(t -> {
      A a = my_map.get(t.getSomething());
      A finalDecision = getFinalDecision(t.getSomeOtherThing(), a);
      my_map.put(t.getSomething(), finalDecision);
      return finalDecision;
}));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your actual goal? `getFinalDecision` will never see an actual value returned by `getSomething()`, only results of `getSomeOtherThing()` and previous evaluations, so where’s the sense in associating it to an entirely unrelated key? And how do you want to split that into two distinct operations, when your `groupingBy` uses the result of `getFinalDecision`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not sure, but it looks like what you actually want to do is more like

```
Map<X,Y> result = myList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(t -> t.getSomething(),
         reducing(null, t -> t.getSomeOtherThing(), (a,b) -> getFinalDecision(b,a) )));
```

where `X` is the return type of `getSomething()` and `Y` is the return type of `getSomeOtherThing()` resp. `getFinalDecision(…)`. Of course, it also works, if `X` and `Y` are the same type.

This mimics the behavior of an initially empty map in your original code, resulting in `null` being passed as second argument to `getFinalDecision` for the first occurrence of every distinct key. Then, the second argument will be the result of the previous `getFinalDecision` evaluation for that key.

It might be that that behavior of your old code only was a compromise, so I’ll mention the alternative. When you use

```
Map<X,Y> result = myList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(t -> t.getSomething(), mapping(t -> t.getSomeOtherThing(),
        collectingAndThen(reducing((a,b) -> getFinalDecision(a,b)), Optional::get))));
```

the value will initially be the result of the first `getSomeOtherThing()` call for every distinct key and `getFinalDecision` will only be called if there are more than one occurrence of the key. Hence, the second argument won’t be `null`, unless `getFinalDecision` itself returned `null` in a previous evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You can using [Map#compute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to simplify your code:

```
test = myList.stream().collect(groupingBy(t -> my_map.compute(t.getSomething()
            ,(it, a) -> getFinalDecision(t.getSomeOtherThing(), a))));
```

**OR** using [Stream#peek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) & [Stream#collect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) to describe it does two things: **merging** && **grouping**.

```
test = myList.stream()
    .map(it -> new SimpleEntry<>(it, getFinalDecision(it.getSomeOtherThing()
                                           , my_map.get(it.getSomething()))))
    .peek(it-> my_map.put(it.getKey(),it.getValue()))
    .collect(groupingBy(SimpleEntry::getValue
                       ,mapping(SimpleEntry::getKey, toList())));
```